# How to remove image input with required field by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did a script that check the image width and remove the image if the width is lesser than certain amount.

The image field is required and after I removed it, it still passed the file validation.

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/AUQYv/3/

```
<form action="">
    <input type="file" id="file" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function (e) {
    var file, img;


    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            if(this.width<490||this.height<175){
            $("#file").val("").change();
            }
        };
        img.onerror = function () {
            alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);


    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.

```
<form action="" id="form" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="file" required accept='image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg'/>
    //your button submit
    <a href="#" id="submitForm">Submit</a>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//When click the button
$('#submitForm').click(function(){
  var validation = true; //Var to validation true
  if($('#file').val()){ //There's image?
      if($('#file').width()<490 || $('#file').height()<175){
          validation = false;
      }
  }else{
     validation = false;
  }
  //Is true?
  if(validation){
    $('#form').submit();
  }else{
    alert("select a image");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer I want.
I set the image field is required and after I removed the image, it still passed the file validation.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand you, can you be most specific with your question please?

Comment: The image is a required field. When you click submit without uploading an image, you can't proceed as it will be asking for an image. But after you uploaded an image that width lesser than 400px, the file is removed but you can proceed without uploading an image.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional statement is setting `file = this.files[0]`.  Change to `==`

Edit:
Since both commenters pointed out that I was wrong, replace
    `$("#file").val("").change()`:

with

```
$("#file").replaceWith($("#file").clone());
```

Comment: This is not meant as a comparison, but as a value assignment. If `this.files[0]` is undefined, then the whole if block does not get executed – if it is not, then `file` has a value that can be worked with within.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer I want. The code is working, just the validation part after we removed the image.
I set the image field is required and after I removed the image, it still passed the file validation.

Comment: I edited my answer with a different solution, since I was mistaken about your conditional statement.

Comment: Thanks. This answer worked but only for the first time.
The 2nd time you upload the same image, it passed the validation
http://jsfiddle.net/AUQYv/6/

Comment: Well shoot, the `change()` method isn't being re-initialized when you enter one the first time, so the `change()` code isn't being called the second time.

Comment: I tried messing with the `validity` attribute of the `$("#file")` item to no avail.  You may need to mess with the form in jquery, and set some of it's attributes to not valid.